# Trying to solve a system of equations with derivatives

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

Given the function

```
f[x_, y_] := E^(-((x^2 + y^2)/3)) (Sin[x^2] + Cos[y^2])
```

I wanted to calculate critical points to this multivariable function as it follows:

```
Solve[D[f[x, y], x] == 0 && D[f[x, y], y] == 0, {x, y}]
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
FindRoot[D[f[x, y], x] == 0 && D[f[x, y], y] == 0, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
f[x_, y_] = E^(-((x^2 + y^2)/3)) (Sin[x^2] + Cos[y^2]);

sol = {x, y, f[x, y]} /. 
         Solve[D[f[x, y], x] == 0 && D[f[x, y], y] == 0, {x, y}, Reals, 
            Method -> Reduce];

pts = DeleteCases[
        Flatten[Table[
            sol /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b}, {a, -4, 4}, {b, -4, 4}], 
                     2], {Undefined, Undefined, Undefined}];

Show[Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 0, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}, All}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the functions are multi-values `Reduce` often does well:

Try the command

```
Reduce[D[f[x,y],x]==0&&D[f[x,y],y]==0,{x,y}]
```